# Cassandra 3.7 with Python, 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode_message'

Tags: python, cassandra

I have a simple python client to fetch data from cassandra. The query string itself runs fine using the DBeaver EE client.

```
def getDataSet(self, station_id, tablename):
    prepared_stmt = self.session.prepare ( "SELECT event_time, reading FROM " +
                                           tablename + " WHERE station_id = ?;")
    bound_stmt = prepared_stmt.bind([station_id])
    rslt = self.session.execute(bound_stmt)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for r in rslt:
        df = df.append(r)
    return df

def __init__(self):
    cluster = Cluster(
        contact_points=['127.0.0.1'],
        )
    self.session = cluster.connect('data')
    self.session.row_factory = tuple_factory
    self.session.client_protocol_handler = NumpyProtocolHandler
```

I get the following exception

`File "/home/david/git/python-example/src/start/fetchcassandra.py", line 13, in getDataSet
    rslt = self.session.execute(bound_stmt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1961, in execute
    return self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile).result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3649, in result
    raise self._final_exception
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {<Host: 127.0.0.1 datacenter1>: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode_message'",)})`

Comment: Updating to Version 3.7.0 of the cassandra python driver solved this problem. It was not listed as a bug in Version 3.6.0 which I was using.

Comment: Same error happens with other Python libraries and `Python v3.7.1` - `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '....'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the NumpyProtocolHander is not built, so you're assigning `None` as the protocol handler.

See [here](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html#optional-non-python-dependencies) for installation notes, and consult your pip log for clues on why it is not being built.